# How to deepen array by having parent id-s (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, nested

The problem is like this. I have a flat array of Comment objects. Every comment object has parent_id in it. Ones without parents have parent_id set to null. 
Now I want to have it nested. I mean like you see in HackerNews for example. For example add a field in Comment object, say children and in that field have all comments that are children or grandchildren or whatever of this comment. I did it with heavy way, I want to see much clearer and much more clever algorithm (I think mine is really heavy). 
Here is my version.

```
find_children(pid = null) => {
  result = comments.filter(pid)
  if(result.length > 0) {
    result.forEach(currentComment => {
      currentComment.children = find_children(currentComment.parent_id)
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: Well actually I wrote the solution and it's working correctly. I want to get some reviews of it if possible, if it's a acceptable solution, can it be improved and so on.

```
export const nest_comments = (comments, parent_id = null) => {
  // defaults to null just to make it easier to call
  const current_children = filter(comments, {'parent_comment': parent_id});
  // first find the children by current parent_id
  if (current_children.length !== 0) { // if it's not empty (termination case)
    // then for each add new field called children which is actually again is
    // chunk of comments, so can be nested, that's why we recurse over
    // array again
    return current_children.map(current_comment => {
      current_comment.children = nest_comments(comments, current_comment.id)
      return current_comment
    })
  }
  else return undefined // undefined as in this case js will ignore the field
    // I think it needs to be other value though
}
```

Comment: Instead of `node.children = find_children(node)` use `find_parent(node).children.push(node)`

Comment: Your `filter` will not work (if comments is a plain array): `filter` needs a function as argument.

Comment: Could you possibly post in your question the array of comments as it is right now? You will need a recursive function to achieve the `parent`->`children`->`grand-children` scheme.

Comment: @Bergi why? Is there any difference?

Comment: @PeterDarmisPet my bad, I wrote pseudo code kind of thing there.

Comment: @Robert Yes, it's a different algorithm :-) And `find_parent` can be easily optimised with a lookup structure. It's what both of the answers do…

Comment: @PeterDarmis The `find_children` code in the question *is* a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem

```js
function createCommentsMap(comments) {
  var commentsMap = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
    commentsMap[comments[i].pid] = comments[i];
  }

  return commentsMap;
}

function createParentChildMap(comments) {
  var parentChildMap = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
    if (!parentChildMap.hasOwnProperty(comments[i].parent_id)) {
      parentChildMap[comments[i].parent_id] = [];
    }

    parentChildMap[comments[i].parent_id].push(comments[i].pid);
  }

  return parentChildMap;
}

function createNestedStructure(startId, parentArray, commentsMap, parentChildMap) {
  if (!parentChildMap.hasOwnProperty(startId)) {
    return;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < parentChildMap[startId].length; i++) {
    var comment = commentsMap[parentChildMap[startId][i]];
    if (!comment.hasOwnProperty('children')) {
      comment['children'] = [];
    }

    parentArray.push(comment);
    createNestedStructure(comment.pid, comment.children, commentsMap, parentChildMap);
  }
}

var comments = [{
    pid: 1,
    parent_id: null
  },
  {
    pid: 2,
    parent_id: 1
  },
  {
    pid: 3,
    parent_id: 1
  },
  {
    pid: 4,
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    pid: 5,
    parent_id: 4
  },
  {
    pid: 6,
    parent_id: 3
  },
]; // Your comments
var commentsMap = createCommentsMap(comments);
var parentChildMap = createParentChildMap(comments);

var nestedStructure = [];
createNestedStructure('null', nestedStructure, commentsMap, parentChildMap);

// In nestedStructure you will get your desired structure
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Map` to key your comments by `id` so to achieve a constant look-up time, when looking for a parent. You could pass this `Map` as the `this` object to a `filter` on the original array, and let that filter add each node to their respective parent's children array, and let that filter return the root.

Here is an implementation:

```js
function makeTree(comments) {
    return comments.filter(function (comment) {
        let p = this.get(comment.parent_id);
        if (p) p.children = (p.children || []).concat(comment);
        return !p;
    }, new Map(comments.map( c => [c.id, c] )))[0];
}

// Sample data
var comments = [
    { id: 1, parent_id: null },
    { id: 2, parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 3, parent_id: 1 },
    { id: 4, parent_id: 2 },
    { id: 5, parent_id: 4 },
    { id: 6, parent_id: 3 },
];

// Perform the conversion
var root = makeTree(comments);

console.log(root);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Could you give me some feedback? Did this answer your question?